# Can't change an UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have an intriguing problem. In my Main.cs code, I have a method which is used to change the UserControl my MainWindow display. Here's the code :

```
public void NextPage()
    {
        if (numberUserControl < 4)
        {
            numberUserControl++;
            SelectUserControl();
        }
    }


    private void SelectUserControl()
    {
        switch (numberUserControl)
        {
            case 1:
                this.contentControl.Content = new UserControls.ServersListControl();
                break;
            case 2:
                this.contentControl.Content = new UserControls.DepartmentsListControl();
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("lol");
                break;
        }
    }
```

(it's not finish, it's why my default display lol)

When I call the method NextPage from my MainWindow, it's works perfectly smooth. But when I use this code :

```
        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.NextPage(/*data*/);
    }
```

The UserControl doesn't change ! I checked with debugger, the code passes in every block, even in the DepartmentsListControl Constructor, but the displayed UserControl doesn't change... And I really can't figure why !

Please help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new instance of `MainWindow` that has no connection to the current instance. It goes out of scope and is lost as soon as the `Button_Click` event ends.

Assuming that the button is in `MainWindow`, just do this:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NextPage(/*data*/);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue now, but the button isn't in MainWindow, he's in another User Control, it's why I created the new instance, to be able to access the method !

Comment: I add the user control in MainWindow by calling `this.contentControl.Content = new UserControls.ServersListControl(ref this);`  
How can I add a reference of MainWindow, it's read only ?